# Android close progress dialog from service

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, android-dialog, android-handler

In my fragment is a button, which when clicked will start a service, which polls sensors, and uses an executor service to store sensor data to the database. The `onClick` of the fragment looks like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recordingStarted){
            try{ 
                recordingStarted = true;
                mainActivity.startService(new Intent(mainActivity, SensorService.class));
                startButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.start_button_label_stop));
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recording...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                mainActivity.logger.e(getActivity(),TAG, "SQL error insertSubject()", e);
            }
        } else {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity);
            dialog.setTitle("Stop recording");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.show();

            mainActivity.stopService(new Intent(mainActivity, SensorService.class));
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Recording stopped.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

`SensorService` class is set up to store sensor data to the database every 10ms using an `ExecutorService`.

The relevant parts of that class are:

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            //get sensor values here

            //insert into database
            try{
                executor.execute(insertHandler);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "insertData: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

        PowerManager manager =
                (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));

        //Executor service and runnable for DB inserts
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        insertHandler = new InsertHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        startForeground(Process.myPid(), new Notification());
        registerListener();
        wakeLock.acquire();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Prevent new tasks from being added to thread
        executor.shutdown();

        try {
            //Wait for all tasks to finish before we proceed
            while (!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for current tasks to finish");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
        }

        //Stop everything else once the task queue is clear
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        unregisterListener();
        wakeLock.release();
        dbHelper.close();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    class InsertHandler implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            dbHelper.insertData(Short.parseShort(MainActivity.subInfo.get("subNum")), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    accelerometerMatrix[0], accelerometerMatrix[1], accelerometerMatrix[2],
                    accelerometerWorldMatrix[0], accelerometerWorldMatrix[1], accelerometerWorldMatrix[2],
                    gyroscopeMatrix[0], gyroscopeMatrix[1], gyroscopeMatrix[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

So when the user hits the button `SensorService` goes through its `onCreate` and `onStartCommand` methods. Whenever sensor data changes, executor service inserts it into the database

When the user hits the button again to stop, I'm telling the executor to shut down, but to finish processing all of its current tasks first. Once executor queue is cleared, we close the database, unregister listeners etc.

During this stage when the executor is awaiting shutdown and clearing its queue, I want to show a progress dialog to the user to say that its going through the process of closing things down.

So I display the progressdialog in the fragment itself once stop button is pressed. But how do I dismiss the dialog only once the executor service has finish processing its queue and is shut down correctly?

I can easily do this with async tasks, but I have chosen to use executor service for this instead so that is not an option

The progress dialog belongs to the fragment, so I cant do something like `MainActivity.dialog.dismiss()` from inside the service. I don't feel like thats a very clean way of handling things anyway

So I guess I'm left with Handlers, but not entirely sure how to set it up in this case because the executor service is operating within another service (`SensorService`). What would the code look like if using a handler to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some mechanism for the service to send a signal to the activity component.  The easiest and most common way to do that is using an event bus.  The proper implementation of this is completely up to you, but you can use existing event bus libraries to help you.  You can find these with a simple google search.